# How to pass props from parent to grandchild in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Instead of hardcoding props, I would love to just pass arbitrary number and types of props from parent to grandchild.

I tried this:

```
<FileListRenderless v-bind="$props" v-on="$listeners">
<!-- <FileListRenderless :attachments="attachments" :isEditMode="isEditMode" :type="type"> -->
```

which works nicely, but I still have to define them in props object in child component. How to also abstract assigning to props object of child component as well ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'd rather not define the props explicitly in the child component then you should just pass the props as an object like:

```
<FileListRenderless :my-props="$props" v-on="$listeners">
```

This bypasses the prop validations built in. You can do the same thing with your listeners, just manually attaching them on component mount. However, I would recommend you rethink your design if you need to do this. If you have a huge range of possible props then you may want to find a way to abstract certain logic out, make factory components, use directives, or use mixins. There are lots of tools in the Vue toolkit.

Comment: I hear ya, maybe I need to rethink things, but your solution is mostly what I was looking for. Only thing is I would have to destructure myProps object to get exact props that were sent from parent, can it be done inside prop definition ?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, no. Its like a compile time vs runtime distinction. The props definition in the child component is interpreted at compile time, but it will only know at runtime what objects are being passed.

Answer (score 1):

Without any more context, I'd recommend passing all props down with `v-bind="$props"`. as you've done.

You can also use a [bus](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/) or vuex, but these would create global-level variables, which is not always ideal.

Comment: I would not recommend using bus though, other than that I will fully agree on your argument